# Not able to find InfragisticsWPF4.Chart Assembly in netadvantage ultimate 2012 vol2

Tags: wpf, silverlight, infragistics

I downlaoded netadvantage ultimate 2012 vol2 and installed it . In earlier versions I was using Infragistics.Windows.Chart namespace by adding  InfragisticsWPF4.Chart.v11.2 Assembly  . But now I am not able to find InfragisticsWPF4.Chart.v12.2 Assembly . What has changed ? How can I add Infragistics.Windows.Chart  namespace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XamChart was retired and is no longer included in NetAdvantage for WPF:
http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/jason_beres/archive/2011/01/01/important-product-changes-and-control-retirements-in-2011-2.aspx